# react native can't set 100% width on children element

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want each item to be 100% width. Adding `alignSelf: 'stretch',` to the style block dose not work.

Please check out the pictures below!

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApyYy.png)

[How it should look](https://cdn.cp.adobe.io/content/2/dcx/d734dcec-6d1f-4f4f-88f7-4525c27b572c/content/artwork/artboard-34386b7b-d89e-42d1-8ed5-7915f266d88a/graphicContent.png/version/5)

My code:

```
<View>
     <ButtonNav style={
                    this.state.currentTab == 'order'
                    ? styles.currentTab
                    : styles.tabItem
                }
                onPress={this.order}
                tagline="BESTÄLLNING" />

</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    navWrapper: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        height: 75,
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#949494',
        flex: 1
    },
    tabItem: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: '#333333',
        flexGrow: 1,
        flex: 1
    },
    currentTab: {
        backgroundColor: '#EEEEEE',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flexGrow: 1,
        borderTopWidth: 2,
        borderTopColor: '#333333',
        flex: 1
    }
});
```

Comment: Please include the code for your `ButtonNav`. And what is `StyleSheet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're having a View parent without flex to the flexxed ButtonNav, so your flexs are being ignored, you can fix it by removing the `<View>` tags, if you need them for some reason, just add a flex style attribute to it, i think this might work:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
     <ButtonNav
         style={
             this.state.currentTab == 'order'
             ? styles.currentTab
             : styles.tabItem
         }
         onPress={this.order}
         tagline="BESTÄLLNING" />

</View>
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right! Feeling really stupid now :( But yes it's obvious to me now. Million thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
navWrapper: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 75,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#949494',
    justifyContent: 'center'
},
tabItem: {
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#333333',
    flexGrow: 1,
    flex: 1,
},
currentTab: {
    backgroundColor: '#EEEEEE',
    flexGrow: 1,
    borderTopWidth: 2,
    borderTopColor: '#333333',
    flex: 1
```

}
   })

try this it should work